# Adding Portugese to HTML/PHP, and small html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm currently editing a website, and I have a couple of small snags I've hit.  In this .php file that I'm editing, I'm changing some language to Portugese, I have it typed below with english characters, but once I add special characters like Ç or Ã my plugin dies (I mean I get a spinning wheel for loading, and it never loads).  This is for a plugin in wordpress.

```
<div id="label_gen_info">' .
                                            'Informacao Geral' .
                                        '</div>'.'<div>' .
                                                '<table>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td>Endereco :</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{1}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td></td>' .
                                                        '<td>{2}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td></td>' .
                                                        '<td>{6}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td style="width:115px">Telefone :</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{14}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td>Horario De Funcionamento :</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{7}</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{11}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td></td>' .
                                                        '<td>{8}</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{12}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td></td>' .
                                                        '<td>{9}</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{13}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td></td>' .
                                                        '<td>{10}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                    '<tr>' .
                                                        '<td>Horario De Compras :</td>' .
                                                        '<td>{15}</td>' .
                                                    '</tr>' .
                                                '</table>' .
                                            '</div>' .'</div>' .
```

Also, I'm trying to edit the format, but I'm not sure what the {15}  (what the {15} actually does) does, so I didn't want to just change things around without knowing first.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so as posted in other places on this forum, my language needed to be set to UTF-8 instead of ASCII.  I'm not entirely sure how to do that, but the instructions on that are a little out of the scope for this question, so I'll leave it to my own research.  To answer the second question, the {15}, and other numbers still confuse me a little, but they apparently are similar to variable calls, since when I changed them, the variables in their places changed.  If anyone wants to clear that up a little bit more, feel free, but for now this is enough of an answer for me (although I'll still be looking into php more, since I'm still a novice.)

Comment: Additionally, if you need to add non-english text to text in html inside of php, use this site.    thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm